# Returning expr not working with sqlite3_exec() in C code

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

Returning expr not working with sqlite3_exec()
gives below error in C code ,
but works fine on sqlite3 terminal

```
sqlite> insert INTO mqtt6 values('abcd',1623066863471168894,1623066863471,119) RETURNING (SELECT sum(size_t) from mqtt6)  ;
76041
sqlite>
```

but when i try to run the same command from C code,
i get error as below:

loki@loki-01 ~/sqlite_dbstat/simple_sqlite - $ ./a.out

```
bytes_written=0  insert OR REPLACE INTO mqtt6 values ('abcd',1623066863471168258,1623066863471168258,119) RETURNING (SELECT sum(size_t) from mqtt6);
**SQL error: near "RETURNING": syntax error**
```

complete C code:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TABLE_NAME "mqtt5"
int main(void) {

        sqlite3 *db;
        char *err_msg = 0;

        int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                sqlite3_close(db);

                return 1;
        }
        //make table
        char *sql_cr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mqtt6 (payload TEXT NOT NULL, timestamp INTEGER , uuid TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,size_t INTEGER);"; 
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql_cr, 0, 0, &err_msg);

        unsigned long long ts=1623066863471168257;
        unsigned long long bytes_written=0;
        char sql[1000]={'\0'};
        char * str="abcd";
        sprintf(sql,"insert  INTO mqtt6 values ('%s',%llu,%llu,%lu) RETURNING (SELECT sum(size_t) from mqtt6);",str,ts,ts,strlen(str)+8+19+4); 
        printf("bytes_written=%llu  %s\n",bytes_written,sql);

        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

                fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

                sqlite3_free(err_msg);        
                sqlite3_close(db);

                return 1;
        } 
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It doesn't look like you are sending the same command in the C code as you are in the terminal.  In the terminal, you are using "insert INTO mqtt6" while in the C code it is "insert OR REPLACE INTO mqtt6 ".  If that is not the issue, please check the string you are creating in the C code; we don't have all of your code here so we have no way of knowing whether it is truly the same as what you wrote in the terminal (aside from the one visible difference).  The first thing to do is to check your assumptions.

Comment: Did you print out, or check in the debugger, what is in the string, sql, after the sprintf and before the sql query is done?

Comment: In the terminal, you do not have a period after "values"  -- you go directly to the open parenthesis. In the C code you first quote, you do.  In the larger code block you included, I do not see the period, so I am not sure which version was run when you got the error.  In any case, look at the string you create with the sprintf and compare that to the string in the terminal.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/7efa3e6c18